# Media query not working for < 480

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm using simple css code one is working other is not.

```
@media (min-width: 480px){
 .image { 
  margin-left: 249px;
 }
}
@media(min-width:985px){
    .col-md-3  {
    width: 207px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 11px;
    }
}
```

if screen is or lower than 985 than it works but not when i bring my browser to 480 and under.

What i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Show us your HTML.  Also, there might be some other CSS rules affecting the .image class, with higher specificity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first rule says `min-width: 480px` so it will only work when the width is 480px or more.

For "480 and under" use `max-width: 480px` instead